# What is the most aesthetic way to to escape a single quote within a single-quoted string in (ba)sh?

Tags: bash, escaping, sh, quotes

In a (ba)sh script of mine, I have, for example:

```
MYVAR='Alice says: "Hello, Bob." But Bob isn't listening.'
```

This is a syntax error, since the ' in `isn't` ends the single-quoted string. I know I can fix this using

```
MYVAR='Alice says: "Hello, Bob." But Bob isn'"'"'t listening.'
```

But that is sooo ugly... what can I do instead? sh doesn't support

```
MYVAR='Alice says: "Hello, Bob." But Bob isn\'t listening.'
```

Which would have been tolerable, and switching to a double-quotes string is not an option for me.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't embed a single quote inside a single quoted string in Bash (or korn shell).  It is a feature of the language you have chosen.  Inside single quotes *there are no special characters*, and that includes `\`.

This is a variation on one of your solutions, and it is ugly:

```
 echo 'Alice says: "Hello, Bob." But Bob isn'\''t listening.'
```

gives:

```
Alice says: "Hello, Bob." But Bob isn't listening.
```

Alternatively use a different language, like Perl or Python.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: yes, and the OP gave that in the question as being "sooo ugly".

Comment: @cdarke I didn't read the question closely enough. Apologies.

Answer (score 2):

A non-POSIX solution which is supported in bash, at least, is the following:

```
MYVAR=$'Alice says: "Hello, Bob." But Bob isn\'t listening.'
```

The `$` causes escape processing.

Comment: Note that this is not guaranteed to work in all shells (`bash` and `zsh` support it, and probably some others. The POSIX standard does not require it, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Using a HEREDOC is a good way to deal with this:

```
read MYVAR << \EOF
Alice says: "Hello, Bob." But Bob isn't listening.
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use double quotes and escaping. I guess, it is simpler than change the language:

```
MYVAR="Alice says: \"Hello, Bob.\" But Bob isn't listening."
```

More information about [escaping symbols](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/quoting.html) in bash.

Comment: "switching to a double-quotes string is not an option for me." Sorry, I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why switching to `$'...'` is an option but switching to double quotes is not (presumably to prevent some sort of parameter expansion). But you don't need to double quote the entire string:

```
MYVAR='Alice says: "Hello, Bob." But Bob '"isn't"' listening.'
```